# In matplotlib pyplot, how to group bars in a bar plot by category?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, categorical-data

First off, I'm not trying to make a regular grouped bar plot.

I have two arrays such as

```
user_score = [70, 95, 86, 50, 17]
user_type = ['High', 'High', 'High', 'Mid', 'Low']
```

I'm trying to create a bar plot such that bars of a same category (`user_type` in this case) are grouped together by separation or color.

Example image of what I'm trying to achieve

[image]
**Fig. 1**

How do I do this in pyplot?

Currently for my actual use case I'm only able to achieve this:

[image]
**Fig. 2**

**Edit:**

**1.**

Actual data:

```
user_utilisation_rating = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06, 0.09, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.16, 0.26, 0.3, 0.53, 0.54, 0.56, 0.76, 0.79, 1.0, 1.0]
user_type = ['Minimum', 'Minimum', 'Minimum', 'Consistent low', 'Consistent low', 'Consistent low', 'Consistent low', 'Consistent low', 'Consistent low', 'Consistent low', 'Consistent low', 'Ending low', 'Ending low', 'Start low', 'Start low', 'Start low', 'Consistent high', 'Consistent high', 'Maximum', 'Maximum']
```

**2.**

Changed Fig 1 to style more similar to what I'm trying to do with regards to my actual plot in Fig 2.

**3.**

Trying to accomplish it with this but only 1 bar appears per `user_type`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
import pandas as pd

user_pd = pd.DataFrame({
    'utilisation' : users_utilisation_rating,
    'type' : user_type
})

user_pd.sort_values(by=['utilisation'], inplace=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (14, 10))

for tp in user_pd['type'].unique():
    ax.bar(user_pd[user_pd['type'] == tp]['type'],
           user_pd[user_pd['type'] == tp]['utilisation'],
           label = tp)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: So, the `user_score` is the y-axis, `user_type` is the color, what is your x-axis?

Comment: Could you please add the relevant source data to the question?

Comment: @Anwarvic the x-axis doesn't matter — the bars just need to be grouped categorically by color or by spacing on the x-axis.

Comment: @Roy2012 Added the actual data I'm using. I'm simulating trust values for users in a cognitive radio network.

Comment: @arcanaxion, I've added an answer that works on your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your data, you can do something like this:

```
color_map = {"Start low": "#581845",
            "Consistent low": "#900C3F",
            "Ending low":"#C70039",
            "Minimum":"#FF5733",
            "Consistent high":"#FFC300",
            "Maximum":"#509916"}


df = pd.DataFrame({"user_rating": user_utilisation_rating,
                  "user_type": user_type})
df.plot.bar(x='user_type', y='user_rating', rot=45,
          color=[color_map[i] for i in user_type])
plt.legend().remove()
plt.show()
```

Which produces something like this:
[image]

**NOTE**: Notice that I've removed the legend as the x-axis does its role

Comment: Thanks! This does the job perfectly for me.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could loop over unique elements in the `'cylinders'` column like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mpg.csv')
df.sort_values(by = ['cylinders', 'mpg'], inplace = True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (14, 10))

for cyl in df['cylinders'].unique():
    ax.bar(df[df['cylinders'] == cyl]['name'],
           df[df['cylinders'] == cyl]['mpg'],
           label = cyl)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

and get this plot:

[image]

---

Alternatively you can use `seaborn.barplot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('mpg.csv')
df.sort_values(by = ['cylinders', 'mpg'], inplace = True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (14, 10))

sns.barplot(x = df['name'],
            y = df['mpg'],
            hue = df['cylinders'],
            dodge = False)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)

plt.show()
```

and get this plot:

[image]

---

Finally, if you want to improve a little the visualization of the bar, you can use a transparency value:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('mpg.csv')
df.sort_values(by = ['cylinders', 'mpg'], inplace = True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (14, 10))

sns.barplot(x = df['name'],
            y = df['mpg'],
            hue = df['cylinders'],
            edgecolor = 'k',
            dodge = False,
            alpha = 0.3)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)

plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I wanted it like [this?](https://i.imgur.com/DfNz84p.jpg) I'm using the source data as in my edited post.

Comment: @JohanC for sure dodge parameter helps to improve the visualization, thanks for the suggestion, I updated my answer

Comment: My apologies, I think the initial example bar plot I posted was misleading. I only have 2 arrays, `user_utilisation_rating` and `user_type`. I want to group the bars with the same `user_type` by color, and indicate as such in the legend.